# How to evaluate Natural Question-Answer Generation pairs?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, model-evaluation, metric, llm

I am trying to generate Natural Question-Answer for a specific domain. I am using a Large Language Model (LLM). I have only context to generate question-answers but don't have any ground truth. How to measure the accuracy or how good the generation is?
I am repeating the experiment 2-3 times, How to compare which question-answers pairs are good? Because each time the generated question-answers are different.

For example,e :

**Context :**

```
"""This section describes our proposed method. The detailed setup for our experiments is described in Sections 4.1 and 4.2."""
```

**Iteration1 (generated question-answer)**

```
Q: This section describes what?
A: This section describes the paper's proposed model.
```

**Iteration2 (generated question-answer)**

```
Q: Which section describes the detailed experiments?
A: Sections 4.1 and 4.2 describes the detailed setup and experiments.
```

**Iteration2 (generated question-answer)**

```
Q: Sections 4.1 and 4.2 describes what?
A: Detailed setup and experiments are described in Sections 4.1 and 4.2
```

Now I want to measure how good this model is in generating questions and answers based on the given paragraph. What matrices I can use? Please guide me on this, and if possible share the papers too.

Answer (score 0):

Without ground truth, it's incredibly hard to measure *real* performance. Even with ground truth, human evaluation is necessary for generation tasks because all automatic metrics unfortunately can be gamed.